# What is the best way to store multiple data type into database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, types, mixed

I am designing a database using MSSQL server 2005 to store log values from different devices.
The datatype of the values can be boolean, int-32 or 64 bit-double

There will be a lookup table called `channels`:

```
ID(PK)      | int32

device_name | varchar(32)
```

There will be a table called `values` to store the value. So boolean and int-32, double values  will be casted to DECIMAL datatype.

```
ID(foreign key to ID@channels)  | int32

logtime                         | DATETIME
value                           | DECIMAL
```

The reason I do that is the end user can select data using a simple select statement on one table, such as 
`select logtime,value from values where ID = 1` without knowing the datatype of the channel.

But this is waste of memory, since now I stored int32 and boolean to Decimal. I am new to database programming, I wonder if anyone know a better way to do this?

Comment: Disk space is cheap - I think your initial approach (convert to decimal) is optimal, no need to fiddle with null values or different fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store 3 individual fields that are nullable. Two will have NULL value, the third will have the actual value (you can even enforce with a CHECK constraint that exactly one of the three is not-NULL). NULL values occupy no space. You can add a computed value that exposes the non-null value as a pseudo-column.

Alternatively you can use a [`sql_variant`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx) field. `sql_variant` can store multiple types and preserve the type metadata (type, precision, scale).

Comment: I think the first solution is better, I am not sure what kind of overhead that sql_variant will bring to me.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of a CHECK constraint that ensures exactly one of the three IS NOT NULL

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable WITH CHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_MyTable_ColumNulls CHECK(
(CASE
   WHEN col1 IS NOT NULL
      THEN 1
   WHEN col2 IS NOT NULL
      THEN 2
   WHEN col3 IS NOT NULL
      THEN 3
   ELSE
      500
END)
=
(CASE
   WHEN col3 IS NOT NULL
      THEN 3
   WHEN col2 IS NOT NULL
      THEN 2
   WHEN col1 IS NOT NULL
      THEN 1
   ELSE
      600
END)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

By using 3 individual fields that are nullable, I created a view called **mixedNumericView** that
uses CASE to select the right column. I assume this way using CASE is inexpensive, am I right? Any alternative ways to do this? The log frequency can be up to every minute, I want to make sure this is the best way to select data.

```
SELECT [ID], [logtime]
      ,'value' = 
      CASE
        WHEN [intValue] is not NULL  THEN [intValue]
        WHEN [bitValue] is not NULL  THEN [bitValue]
        WHEN [floatValue] is not NULL THEN [floatValue]
        ELSE NULL
       END
  FROM [dbo].[mixedNumericView]
```

Comment: You can use a computed column on the table itself: `ALTER TABLE ... ADD [value] AS COALESCE(IntValue, COALESCE(bitValue, floatValue))`

Comment: @Remus - Or `COALESCE(IntValue,bitValue, floatValue)` presumably.

Comment: @Martin: I guess it was the right time for me to learn that coalesce accepts an open list of arguments...